# Does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and 'cannot convert from methodgroup' in Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting an error which I can't find the solution to, it's that my model does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' (I put the whole error lower in the post), I've read about it around Stack Overflow, all answers seem to point towards `using system.Linq` and `using system.Data`, but I have them in the code.

The program is supposed to take some data from tables: Contatti, Contacts and Companies which are at different locations and bring them together (which happen in the list of the GET method in the controller), the code is the following:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

 public partial class ContactsUni2
{
    public IEnumerable<Contatti> Contattis { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Controller GET Which Gives the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ContactManager.Models;

namespace ContactManager.Controllers
{
public class ContactsUni21Controller : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private ContattiDB2 db2 = new ContattiDB2();

    // GET: ContactsUni21
    public ActionResult Index(String Page)
    {
        ContactsUni2 CU = new ContactsUni2();
        CU.Contattis = db.Contattis.Include(i => i.ContattoID);
        CU.Contacts = db.Contacts;
        CU.Companies = db.Companies;
        List<ContactsUni2> contactlist = new List<ContactsUni2>();
        contactlist.Add(CU.AsEnumerable()); // The error is HERE at CU.AsEnumerable(), cannot convert from method group to 'contactsuni2'
        return View(contactlist);
    }
```

View, which also gives a similar error but for Contatti.Count()

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactManager.ViewModels.ContactsUni3>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Contacts Unified</h2>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Nome)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Citta)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.ContattoID)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.CodicePostale)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatti.Email)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.Address)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.CompanyId)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact.ContactId)
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)

        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < @item.Contatti.Count(); i++) // Second Error Here
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Contatti[i].Nome
                    @item.Contatti[i].Citta
                    @item.Contatti[i].ContattoID
                    @item.Contatti[i].CodicePostale
                    @item.Contatti[i].Email
                    @item.Contatti[i].Address
                    @item.Contatti[i].CompanyId
                    @item.Contatti[i].ContactId
                    @item.Contatti[i].CompanyName

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ContattoID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ContattoID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ContattoID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

First error in Controller GET Method:

> Error CS1929  'ContactsUni2' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataTable)' requires a receiver of type 'DataTable'

when I try doing that, it says:

> cannot convert from method group to 'contactsuni2'

Second Error in View loop:

> Error CS1061  'Contatti' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'Contatti' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have those namespaces in code, but not in your views. Add `@using System.Linq` in your view, or in your view's configuration.

Comment: Didn't you meant CU.Contacts.AsEnumerable()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this:

```
contactlist.Add(CU);
```

The method `List.Add()` expects a single item, and CU is a single item.

And to fix the problem in your View: simply add a line with `@using System.Linq` on top so the compiler will know where to look.

*Additional info about AsEnumerable:*

You only need `AsEnumerable()` if you have a collection or sequence of items, *but* that collection is incompatible with a construct such as `foreach (var item in collection)`.
In that case you can try using `foreach (var item in collection.AsEnumerable())`.

In some cases the .NET Framework may then already provide the implementation of `.AsEnumerable()`, in other cases you may have to provide it yourself. But in the case of your question you don't even need it at all.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the first problem, the second though @using System.Linq did not help, i still can't iterate through it it says cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type contatti/contacts/companies. And i need to get specific columns from each of those tables.

Comment: Your collection is defined as `public IEnumerable<Contatti> Contattis`. And `IEnumerable<...>` does not support indexing with `[i]`, it only supports enumerating with e.g. `foreach`. You can solve this by changing it to: `public List<Contatti> Contattis`. This may cause other changes to be needed, e.g. when assigning it, just add `.ToList()` if/when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate issues:

1. In your `ContactsUni21Controller` you're calling `AsEnumerable` on an object that does not implement `IEnumerable`; you're trying to add an instance of `ContactsUni2` to a `List<ContactsUni2>` there's no need for a cast here since it's an instance of the same type that the list is containing
2. As @CodeCaster mentioned, you're not putting a `@using System.Linq;` statement in your Razor view, preventing you from accessing the `IEnumerable.Count` method

Comment: Thank you, that solved the first problem, the second though @using System.Linq did not help, i still can't iterate through it it says cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type contatti/contacts/companies. And i need to get specific columns from each of those tables.

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't support indexing and getting; you need to either call `ToList` and then perform your indexing, or you need to change your view model properties from `IEnumerable` to `List`